# What is the time complexity of this? It uses 3 loops and the innermost loop depends on the outermost?

Tags: functional-programming, time-complexity

```
function fun(N) {
    
    let k = 0;
    for(let i = N; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
        for (let g = 1; g <= N/i;g = g + 1) {
            for (let h =1; h <= i;h = h + 1) {
                k = k + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

My analysis of the given problem is as follows:

The outer loop runs until i becomes less than 1, and in each iteration, i is divided by 2. This implies that the outer loop will run logarithmically in base 2 with respect to N. Specifically, the outer loop will run until i becomes less than 1, and the number of iterations can be expressed as log₂(N).

The middle loop runs for N/i times, where i is the control variable of the outer loop. Therefore, the middle loop contributes a factor of N to the time complexity.

The innermost loop runs i times, and is dependent on the outer loop. Thus we do not consider its time complexity.

Therefore, overall time complexity of the function is O(N log N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer of a time complexity of `O(N log N)` is correct, but your derivation is not.

Consider the inner two loops involving `g` and `h`. The innermost loop with index `h` runs `i` times, thus having complexity `O(i)`. The loop with index `j` runs `N/i` times, thus having complexit `O(N/i)`. As these two loops are nested, the total complexity is `O(i) * O(N/i) = O(N)`. Therefore, the time complexity of the inner two loops is independent of `i` and is always `O(N)`.

The outermost loop with index `i` runs `O(log N)` times, and your logic behind this is correct.

Thus, the total time complexity of all three loops is `O(log N) * O(N)`, giving an answer of `O(N log N)`.